# Prime Ideals pertaining to Polynomials

Tags: ring-theory

Let F be a field, and let f ∈ F[X] be non-zero. Then the
following are equivalent:

(i) the ideal (f) = {fg : g ∈ F[X]} is maximal;

(ii) the ideal (f) is prime;

(iii) the polynomial f is irreducible in F[X].

I get the reasoning between i and ii by using the following theorem and its corollary:

Let R be a commutative unital ring, and let I be a proper ideal.
Then I is maximal if and only if R/I is a field.

Let R be a commutative unital ring. Then every maximal ideal
of R is prime.

How would you arrive at (iii) assuming (ii) is true?

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more background about what results you know? Because $(ii)\implies (iii)$ is direct consequence of the fact that if $R$ is a (unital commutative ring) and $(a)$ is a prime ideal of $R$, then $a$ is irreducible in $R$ but I assume you don't know that.

Comment: In general since $F$ is a field, then $F[X]$ is a PID and in a generic PID $R$ an ideal $(a)$ is maximal iff prime iff $a$ is irreducible, which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @Temoi Is there a way to show that if we do have a prime ideal (f) this polynomial is irreducible directly from the definition of irreducibility?

Comment: Suppose $f=gh$. Then $f=gh\in (f)$. Since $(f)$ is prime, you have $g\in (f)$ or $h\in (f)$. You can assume $h\in (f)$, so $h=fk=gkh$ which implies deg$(gk)=0$, i.e. (since $gk\neq 0$) $g\in F^{*}$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): instead of asking for a solution in comments, edit your post to show your attempts, even if they failed. To begin with, recall the definitions to be used (prime ideal and irreducible element).

Comment: @Temoi Since $(f)$ prime $\implies f$ irreducible holds in any commutative domain, better not speak about $\deg(gk)$. Instead, conclude directly $gk=1$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Sure, you are right! (btw, domains are always assumed to be commutative :) )